# Updating custom file path in UI panel

Tags: python, interface, properties

I have an object property group with a ccustom filepath:

```
class PROPS_UL_ProxyObjectSettings(PropertyGroup):    

    #create string property for Proxy Path
    proxy_path : StringProperty(
        name = "Proxy Path",
        default = "//Proxy.blend",
        description = "Define the directory to store the proxy object file",
        subtype = 'FILE_PATH',
        )
```

The addon will show this filepath inside the UI panel:

```
...
row.prop(proxy_object_settings, "proxy_path")
...
```

When I do it like this the filepath itself works but the box in the UI is always set to the default value defined in the PropertyGroup.
How can I show and update the filepath inside the UI panel everytime the active object changes. It should look like the following:

filepath = "//" + active object + ".blend"

Comment: Why even make this a property the user can edit?  Consider a rethink to make the directory and extension a property and simply put the context object name  property  inbetween in UI.

Comment: @batFINGER I admit the example too simple. My plan is to use the filepath to write a hi res object to another blend file and substitute it with a low res proxy object, then relink the hi res object at rendertime. Of course the user should be able to define a custom path that he wants to save the object to. Also, in case the location of the files change you would have to correct the path (stored in the proxy object) to tell blender where it can find the according object data. I assumed the best way to store this information is a custom object property.